# Changing width of child view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I added child view controller to parent view controller programmatically in swift 3.0.

But I do not want the child view controller width as full screen, I want to customise the width and height of the child view controller. I tried to open the custom size child view controller, but it is not working.

```
// Here is my code

let secondViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: storyBoardName)
secondViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.custom
secondViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width-500, height: self.view.bounds.height)
self.present(secondViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I recommend creating a custom view, not an entire view controller on the storyboard for this kind of use. Create a custom view in storyboard, give it an id, instantiate the view inside the parent view controller and add it onto your parent view. If you need any kind of controller for your view, just write one and let it instantiate the view, and provide a method for the parent view controller to attach the given child view.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are not adding the secondViewController as childview controller. You are presenting that view controller. There is a difference.

You are trying to use `UIModalPresentationStyle.custom` to present viewcontroller using custom style. But using this custom style is not this trivial.

From [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PresentingaViewController.html):

> Creating a custom style involves
>   subclassing UIPresentationController and using its methods to animate
>   any custom view onto the screen and to set the size and position of
>   the presented view controller. The presentation controller also
>   handles any adaptations that occur because of changes to the presented
>   view controller’s traits

It tells you that you need to subclass `UIPresentationController` and subclass its method(with other methods) `- (CGRect)frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView` to set the frame of the presented viewcontroller.

More is explained in [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/DefiningCustomPresentations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH25-SW1).

You can ofcourse achieve all this by actually adding a childviewcontroller. 
Steps would be like this:

1. Create your child viewcontroller instance.
2. Set its view frame to whatever you want.
3. **Add its view as a subview** on to parent view controller's view using `addSubview:`
4. Call [addChildViewController] on parent viewcontrller (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621394-addchildviewcontroller)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're trying to do, when I want to show some UI on top of another UIViewController I usually use a fullscreen view controller with `self.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen`. Then I create another view which has the visible size I actually want to show to the user. This allows you to do pretty much anything you want.

But if you want an actual child viewcontroller, you need to use the [appropriate functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html) for it.